# Fill a nxn matrix in spiral order from 1 to n²

Tags: c

I was supposed to fill an nxn matrix in spiral order from 1 to n²  using functions and then print its result but I don't know why my code doesn't function can anyone help please?

The principle was to create different functions, each filling the matrix at different time intervals then calling those functions in the main program which prints them in a spiral matrix.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* initializing the array and variables for the whole program*/
int A[5][5],top,bottom,left,right;

int FillRowForward(int A[5][5],int top,int left,int right,int z)
/*function that fills the top of the matrix from left to right*/
{   left = 0;
        for(top=left,right=0;right<=4;right++)
    {
        A[top][right]=z;
        z++;

    }
    return A[top][right];
}
int FillRowBackwards(int A[5][5],int bottom,int left,int right,int z)
/*fills the lower part from  right to left*/
{   bottom =4;

    for(left=bottom,right=4;right>=0;right--)
    {
        A[left][right-1]=A[left][right]+z;
    }
    return A[left][right-1];
}

int FillColumnDownward(int A[5][5],int top,int bottom,int left,int z)
/*fills the last column from top to bottom*/
{
    left=0;
 for(top=left,bottom=4;top<=4;top++)
    {
        A[top+1][bottom]= A[top][bottom]+z;
    }
    return A[top][bottom];
}
int FillColumnUpward(int A[5][5],int top,int bottom,int left, int z)
/*fills the first column from bottop to top*/
{
    left =0;
    for(bottom=left,top=0;bottom>=1;bottom--)
    {
         A[bottom-1][top]=A[bottom][top]+z
    }
    return A[bottom][top];
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,k=1;


    while(k<5*5){
    int FillRowForward(int A[5][5],int top,int left,int right,int k);
    top++;
    int FillColumnDownward(int A[5][5],int top,int bottom,int right,int k);
    right--;
    int FillRowBackwards(int A[5][5],int bottom,int left,int right,int k);
    bottom--;
    int FillColumnUpward(int A[5][5],int top,int bottom,int left,int k);
    }
//prints the matrix
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
        for(j=0;j<=4;j++)
            printf("%d",A[i][j]);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to *call* the functions. In `main()` you are only providing declarations of the functions, not calling them. They should really be near the top of the code, underneath `#include <stdlib.h>` as they do not provide any functionality by placing them in `main()`.

Comment: You should start with one function, that you call from `main` once. Then print the matrix to see the partial answer. When that works properly, you can write and test the next function. Once you've got all four functions working properly to draw the outer ring, you can call the functions a second time, and see how that goes.

Comment: `while(k<5*5){...}` Where do you change `k`? I don't see it change so it looks like an endless loop

Comment: Having global variables `A`, `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` hidden by variables with the same names in the various function definitions is called 'shadowing' and can easily lead to confusion.  Those global variables should be defined inside `main()`.  If you use GCC, you can add `-Wshadow` to get warnings about shadowed variables.  It's yet another reason to avoid global variables whenever you can.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here:

1. I suppose there is no need for global variables, so you can define everything in the `main()` function
2. As already pointed out "In `main()` you are only providing declarations of the functions, not calling them. "
3. You have an infinite loop in `main()` function because you never increased var k
4. Try to avoid using numbers in your function, use variables or symbolic constants instead. No difference on such small projects, but in bigger projects, you can easily confuse them, also if you want to change, you must change every value, etc.

Your functions are not doing what they are supposed to do. You can write something like this (I found my old program and modified it a bit):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_mat(int mat[][5], int m, int n)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", mat[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void spiral(int mat[][5], int m, int n)
{
    int i, k = 0, l = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    
    while(k < m && l < n)
    {
        for(i = l; i < n; i++)
        {
            mat[k][i] = counter++;
        }
        k++;

        for(i = k; i < m; i++)
        {
             mat[i][n-1] = counter++;
        }
        n--;

        if(k < m)
        {
            for(i = n-1; i >= l; i--)
            {
                mat[m-1][i] = counter++;
            }
            m--;
        }

        if(l < n)
        {
            for(i = m-1; i >= k; i--)
            {
                mat[i][l] = counter++;
            }
            l++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int mat[5][5];
    int n = 5;

    spiral(mat,n,n);
    
    print_mat(mat,n,n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Since you need to create different functions, you can try to divide this `spiral()` function into several smaller functions, it can be a good exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems like:

```
int FillRowForward(int A[5][5],int top,int left,int right,int k);
```

not being a function call and that you you never change `k`, i.e. you have an endless loop.

This solution uses a variable `direction` to track the current direction of filling the matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRSIZE 10

int main()
{
    int A[ARRSIZE][ARRSIZE] = { 0 };
    int i=0, j=0;
    int direction = 0;

    for(int k = 1; k <= (ARRSIZE*ARRSIZE); ++k)
    {
        A[i][j] = k;
        
        switch (direction)
        {
            case 0 :  // Go rigth
                if (((j + 1) == ARRSIZE) || (A[i][j+1] != 0))
                {
                    // Switch direction
                    direction = 1;
                    ++i;
                }
                else
                {
                    ++j;
                }
                break;
            case 1 :  // Go down
                if (((i + 1) == ARRSIZE) || (A[i+1][j] != 0))
                {
                    // Switch direction
                    direction = 2;
                    --j;
                }
                else
                {
                    ++i;
                }
                break;
            case 2 :  // Go left
                if (((j - 1) == -1) || (A[i][j-1] != 0))
                {
                    // Switch direction
                    direction = 3;
                    --i;
                }
                else
                {
                    --j;
                }
                break;
            case 3 :  // Go up
                if (((i - 1) == -1) || (A[i-1][j] != 0))
                {
                    // Switch direction
                    direction = 0;
                    ++j;
                }
                else
                {
                    --i;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<ARRSIZE; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<ARRSIZE; j++)
            printf("%4d",A[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  11
  35  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  45  12
  34  63  84  85  86  87  88  71  46  13
  33  62  83  96  97  98  89  72  47  14
  32  61  82  95 100  99  90  73  48  15
  31  60  81  94  93  92  91  74  49  16
  30  59  80  79  78  77  76  75  50  17
  29  58  57  56  55  54  53  52  51  18
  28  27  26  25  24  23  22  21  20  19
```